# How to publish web MVC (EF-database first)?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, publish

I have read many document about publish web MVC. Almost is about publish MVC-EF(code first) to Azure.

So, what about MVC-EF(database first) ?

It had better not to Azure ( Example: www.gearhost.com)

Comment: can you provide more info about your scenario ? It's not clear for me.

Comment: In MVC project, I have used entity framework (Database first) to work with database.

Comment: Now, I wants to publish it (move from localhost to intenet). That is all

Comment: azure or else? do you have a host service provider?

Comment: Not Azure. Im using gearhost ( service provider )

Comment: why don't you like azure?

Comment: Because I have read one document about publish it. It's so hard for me

Comment: OK,please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hence your service provider is `Gearhost`,you can follow below mentioned steps.

**How to publish your app from Visual Studio**

> Publishing your application from Visual Studio is simple and easy with
>   GearHost regardless of your Visual Studio version.

**Download the publishing file**

> We make it easy to publish from Visual Studio by providing you a fully
>   encapsulated publishing file that you will import into Visual Studio.
>   To get this file you will need to:
>
> Log in to your GearHost account Click the CloudSite name you want to
>   upload your application to Click the Publish tab Click the Visual
>   Studio button under the Application Publishing Files heading This will
>   download a {cloudsitename}.publish file to your local computer
>   storage.

**Publishing**

- Launch Visual Studio and open your existing web application project
- Right click on your web application and select Publish Web App
- In the Publish wizard window select Profile and select Import under
  the Select a publish target menu
- Browse to the {cloudsitename}.publish file you downloaded above and
  select OK
- Click the Publish button

[image]

Here is the Link : [**How to publish your app from Visual Studio**](https://www.gearhost.com/documentation/how-to-publish-your-app-from-visual-studio)

**How to create a database**

> You can create a MSSQL (Microsoft SQL) or MySQL database on your
>   account using the simple steps below. To restore a database from a
>   backup view the How to restore a database doc.

**To create a database:**

- Log in to your GearHost Account
- Click the Databases menu
- Click the Create Database button
- Enter a desired database name
- Select the database Plan and Type
- Click the Create Empty Database button to complete
- Connect to your database:

> Congrats you now have a new database! To connect to your MSSQL
>   database view the How to connect to a MSSQL Database doc. To connect
>   to your MySQL database view the How to connect to a MySql Database
>   doc.

Here is the Link : [**How to create a database**](https://www.gearhost.com/documentation/create-a-database)

Comment: Yes, I have tried it.  it's not include database( When i access database after publish, bug happens)

Comment: you have to create a db also.

Comment: Please see my post above.

Comment: ya. I forgot 'To create database' . Now i will try it

Comment: OK,Good Luck ! :)

Comment: tks you so much. I hopes success come to me

Comment: Wow. Finally. Im success. tks bro so much

Comment: It's easy and simple. the best way i want... i just want say... tks you ... tks you so much...

Comment: because im newbie on stackoverflow. i will +1 for you later as soons as i can

Comment: Thanks mate.Sure.I'll really appreciate it :)